# Does freedom leave us 'determined' to be free?

Tags: free-will, linguistics, freedom

I am wondering what the error in reasoning is that asks why it is that freedom appears to leave us determined to be free, and whether this is itself not a form of unfreedom.

If we are by nature free, this might seem incoherent because we are then not free to be unfree. But I am assuming I'm missing something here. I am wondering if this is perhaps a linguistic confusion of some sort.

Comment: An assumed axiom cannot undermine itself. Can a mouth (which is to eat) eat itself?

Comment: Another moment is that we can freely choose to behave _as if_ we are not free. Here two planes, the primary and the secondary, get superposed, by they are not mixed or merged.

Comment: It is a linguistic confusion, in the words "determine" and "freedom". What "determine" usually means is not merely constraining action, but prescribing it completely, so freedom to be free is not a determination, only a constraint. And "freedom" as complete lack of constraints is unintelligible anyway because describing what it is a freedom *of* already constrains it. What "freedom" usually means instead is merely lack of determination, sometimes some specific constraints are ruled out as well (as in freedom *from*).

Comment: @Conifold is there a name for this sort of linguistic confusion?

Comment: I do not think there is a universally accepted term, but some authors call this [determination fallacy](https://www.informationphilosopher.com/freedom/determination_fallacy.html), [fallacy of causal determinism](https://www.csus.edu/indiv/m/mayesgr/phl4/handouts/phl4causalfallacies.htm) ("*asserting or denying a causal relationship based on the fact that the proposed cause does not immediately, absolutely, or uniquely determine the effect*") or [confusing necessary with a sufficient condition](https://www.txstate.edu/philosophy/resources/fallacy-definitions/Confusion-of-Necessary.html).

Comment: Why would you expect freedom to include freedom to be unfree? Physically, it doesn't include freedom to sprout wings and fly,  morally, it doesn't include the freedom to limit the freedom of others, and logically it doesn't include the freedom to contradict itself. "Free" doesn't mean "omnipotent" or "unconstrainted". I'm just not seeing the difficulty here.

Answer (score 1):

Freedom is always the freedom of choice. Regardless of the circumstances you can and you must choose what you do. The circumstances can only limit the number and quality  of options available but in the end you make the final choice. Always.

We are determined to be free, we did not choose to be free and we cannot choose to be unfree. Freedom is the opportunity to choose, we cannot choose freedom before we have it and we don't need to choose it after we've got it. Correspondingly, we cannot choose not to have the opportunity to choose. You cannot unchoose something you did not choose in the first place.

Comment: Freedom is more than freedom of choice, which assumes that the options are already available and conceived. That is a very limited aspect of it. A deeper freedom is in being able to generate the options themselves, starting with conceiving them in the first place.

Comment: @Conifold Naturally freedom of choice requires options. The options are seldom readily presented like in a restaurant menu. More often than not you have to figure them out yourself and if you're smart you can come up with new creative options besides the more obvious ones. The more and the better options you have, the more freedom you have and the better results you can expect.

Comment: To conceive or understand (the meaning of) an option is to choose it. While we'are at the one chosen (my possibility), we can't comprehend other ones, its alternatives. We are aware of them, but keep them in abstract form of "formal" or "someone's else" possibilities, seeing them under that different perspective. (So, we don't select by rational comparison between what we are on and what we could be at instead). And we do not generate options, they are given as part of the situation (partly including our past, now alienated still compelling choices).